# VideoJS DASH video not loading

Tags: video, video-streaming, video.js, mpeg-dash

I'm trying to use `videojs` & `videojs\http-streaming` to play dash videos on my site. Up until now I've used `videojs-contrib-dash` and had no problems but I've found that `http-streaming` is now the official videojs solution for http streaming.

I have a specific video which is hosted on Amazon S3 with public access that won't play on `vhs` demo:
https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bucketvod/b0PCWLt690M9/mpd.mpd.

It does, however, play on other dash players such as `shaka-player` and `videojs-contrib-dash` demo player. I'm not sure if this is some encoding problem or `vhs` specific problem. I've posted an issue on their hub:
https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/issues/209